# How to remove numbers from text in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala, text, apache-spark

How to remove numbers form a text in Scala ?

for example i have this text:

```
canon 40 22mm lens lock strength plenty orientation 321 .
```

after removing :

```
canon lens lock strength plenty orientation .
```

Comment: use this regex `"\\d"` and then replace the match with empty string.

Comment: Just to be clear - it's not *just* the numbers you want removed, right? In your example, `mm` is also gone.

Comment: My solution below removes all words that contain at least one number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, try `filter` or `filterNot`

```
val text = "canon 40 22mm lens lock strength plenty orientation 321 ."
val without_digits = text.filter(!_.isDigit)
```

or

```
val text = "canon 40 22mm lens lock strength plenty orientation 321 ."
val without_digits = text.filterNot(_.isDigit)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\\d+\\S*\\s+
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/1

Answer (score 1):

Since it is apparent, you want to remove all words that contain a number, because in your example `mm` is also gone, because it is prefixed by a number.

```
val s = "That's 22m, which  is gr8."
s.split(" ").filterNot(_.exists(_.isDigit)).mkString(" ")

res8: String = That's which  is
```